# Wordpress= display x number of randomly selected images from gallery field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin in Wordpress to implement a gallery into my site. I would like to display 5 random images from the gallery field.

I have the following code which displays all images from the gallery field:

```
    <?php $images = get_field('gallery');
      if( $images ): ?>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
          <img scr="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
        <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <?php endif;  ?>
```

Print_r of $images results in the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 46 [alt] => [title] => 500x10002 [caption] =>  [description] =>   [url] => 500x1000.jpg [sizes] => Array ( [thumbnail] => 500x1000-100x100.jpg [medium] => 500x1000-150x300.jpg [large] => 500x1000.jpg [post-feature-image] => 500x1000.jpg ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 45 [alt] => [title] => 500x500 [caption] => [description] =>   [url] => 500x500.jpg [sizes] => Array ( [thumbnail] => 500x500-100x100.jpg [medium] => 500x500-300x300.jpg [large] => 500x500.jpg [post-feature-image] => 500x500.jpg ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 44 [alt] => [title] => 2000x500 [caption] => [description] =>   [url] => 2000x500.jpg [sizes] => Array ( [thumbnail] => 2000x500-100x100.jpg [medium] => 2000x500-300x75.jpg [large] => 2000x500-1024x256.jpg [post-feature-image] => 2000x500-610x152.jpg ) ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 43 [alt] => [title] => 1000x500 [caption] => [description] =>   [url] => 1000x500.jpg [sizes] => Array ( [thumbnail] => 1000x500-100x100.jpg [medium] => 1000x500-300x150.jpg [large] => 1000x500.jpg [post-feature-image] => 1000x500-610x305.jpg ) ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 42 [alt] => [title] => 500x2000 [caption] => onderschifttttt [description] =>   [url] => 500x2000.jpg [sizes] => Array ( [thumbnail] => 500x2000-100x100.jpg [medium] => 500x2000-75x300.jpg [large] => 500x2000-256x1024.jpg [post-feature-image] => 500x2000.jpg ) ) )
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I just couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic might look like this:

```
$max_images_to_show = 5;
$images_available = count($images);
$images_to_show = array();

if ($images_available <= $max_images_to_show) {
    $images_to_show = $images;
} else {
    while(count($images_to_show) < $max_images_to_show) {
        $random_index = rand(0, count($images) - 1);
        $images_to_show[] = array_slice($images, $random_index, 1);
    }
}

// show images from $images_to_show
```

Comment: This works but the output often contains duplicates. Any way to get rid of those?

Comment: You would need to make sure the initial `$image` array doesn't have duplicates. The `array_slice` actually removes the selected images from the `$images` array, so they are not being picked twice.